# `object' does not contain a definition for `layerCount'

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

After updating Unity I face the problem

```
Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Editor/PhotonNetwork/Views/PhotonAnimatorViewEditor.cs(83,57):
error CS1061: Type `object' does not contain a definition for `layerCount' and no extension method `layerCount' of type `object' could be found.
Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

```
private int GetLayerCount()
{
    #if UNITY_5 || UNITY_5_0 || UNITY_2017
    return (this.m_Controller == null) ? 0 : this.m_Controller.layers.Length;
    #else
    return (m_Controller == null) ? 0 : this.m_Controller.layerCount;
    #endif
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what PUN version is this? looks very old. update to latest and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I’m guessing that you updated to Unity 2018.x. The reason the code won‘t compile is because all the preprocessors like UNITY_2017 are false for Unity 2018.

I would recommend to update also photon from the unity asset store, since they should support Unity 2018.

But if you want to fix it yourself: A quick fix would be add UNITY_2018

```
private int GetLayerCount()
{
    #if UNITY_5 || UNITY_5_0 || UNITY_2017 || UNITY_2018
    return (this.m_Controller == null) ? 0 : this.m_Controller.layers.Length;
    #else
    return (m_Controller == null) ? 0 : this.m_Controller.layerCount;
    #endif
}
```

Or just remove the line for Unity 4 and older, since you don‘t need it anymore

```
private int GetLayerCount()
{
    return (this.m_Controller == null) ? 0 : this.m_Controller.layers.Length;
}
```